# Rename DB Fields after Bake

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bake

i realised (after baking and much customisation) that i can use DB fields called 'created' and 'modified' (as long as the are type Datetime and default NULL) to get built in functionality to save 'created on date' and 'modified on date' saved to DB on add and edit. 
So i renamed my 2 fields to 'created' and 'modified' but the db values in the fields remain NULL after adding and updating.
what have i missed? can one not rename DB fields after baking? 
(i did replace the old field names with the new ones in the views.)
any help would be appreciated....
Vauneen

Answer (score 0):

Did you delete the all Model cache files in /tmp/cache/models/ before testing it out?